# calling an index in bytes

Tags: python, byte

I'm experimenting with bytes in python 3 and I'm getting a strange result.  When I convert a character to hex I get a predictable result.  `ord('t') == 116`, which is equal to 7*16 + 4.  This is reasonable since:

```
binascii.hexlify(b't') == b'74'
```

What I don't understand is why `b'74'[0] == 55`.  Where is the 55 coming from?

Comment: 55 = 0x37 is the ASCII code for '7', i.e., `chr(55) == '7'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b'74'[0]` is `'7'`. Character `'7'` is 55 in ASCII

Comment: so it interprets the bytes individually when you call it instead of considering them a pair like in hex.

Comment: @Rob They are still both strings hence iterable hence you can have access to symbols by their indices.

Comment: @Rob `b'74'` is a literal bytes object containing two bytes. Take a look at `b't'[0]`

Comment: @Rob Yes. First byte (`b'74'[0]`) contains `'7'` (as ascii symbol) so `55` (as a number).